# Android how to load image from url and put it on top

Tags: android, url, imageview

Actually I have done the "load from url" part but the result is not satisfying.

I wnat the image placed on the top. However, when it loaded the image, it automatically align to center but I have declared `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` .

Besides, I'd like to have some text on the image but the text are always on the top left corner..........

here are my codes:
(xml)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/product_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/white" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/product_image"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/product_price"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

activity:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PostDetail extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_detail);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        WPTemplateDB dpOpener = new WPTemplateDB(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dpOpener.getReadableDatabase();
        //Log.d("passed pid", getIntent().getStringExtra("pid")+"");
        Cursor cursor = db.query(WPTemplateDB.PRODUCT_TABLE, 
                                new String[]{WPTemplateDB.TITLE, WPTemplateDB.IMAGE, WPTemplateDB.PRICE}, 
                                WPTemplateDB.PRODUCT_ID+"=?", 
                                new String[]{getIntent().getStringExtra("pid")}, 
                                null, null, null);
        String title = "", price = "", img = "";
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            title = cursor.getString(0);            
            img = cursor.getString(1);
            price = cursor.getString(2);
        }
        Log.d("title", title);
        Log.d("img_src", img);
        TextView productTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.product_title);
        ImageView productImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.product_image);
        TextView productPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.product_price);

        new LoadImageFromURL(productImage).execute(img);
        productTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(title),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);       
        productPrice.setText(price);
    }

    private class LoadImageFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{
        ImageView bitmapImgView;
        public LoadImageFromURL(ImageView bmImgView){
            bitmapImgView = bmImgView;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String urlStr = params[0];
            Bitmap img = null;

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlStr);
            HttpResponse response;
            try {
                response = (HttpResponse)client.execute(request);           
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                BufferedHttpEntity bufferedEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
                InputStream inputStream = bufferedEntity.getContent();
                img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return img;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap){
            bitmapImgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_post, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this,
                    new Intent(this, ListPost.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have declared image view width as android:layout_width="match_parent". Change to fill_parent..and try, it may work.

Comment: @Brinda: the image still places to the middle of screen:(

Comment: @Brinda-user1594986 : match_parent and fill_parent are the same.

Comment: make relative layout_width also fill_parent

Comment: tried fill parent but not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use wrap_content instead match_parent for product_image's android:layout_width, and   you should use FrameLayout if you want put text on the ImageView. like:

```
      <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="test"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I'd like to know how to achieve it by framelayout

Comment: how can I customize the text position? for example, to bottom right corner:)